# How to use the @ApiResponse annotation in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, swagger, swagger-ui

I am working with kotlin and I am using swagger to document my rest services.

I am not pretty sure of how can I use the @ApiResponse annotation in kotlin, I am doing the next:

```
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponses( ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "..."),
                ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "..."),
                ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "..."),
                ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "..."),
                ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "...") )
    })
```

But I am getting the next issue:

> An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to:

```
@ApiResponses(
        value = [
            ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "..."),
            ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "..."),
            ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "..."),
            ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "..."),
            ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "...")
        ]
)
```

Comment: I got the issue: Only const val can be used in constants expressions

Comment: @rasilvap Are your `messages` constant values (raw strings)?

Comment: They could be constant values, but at the moment I don't have a predefined format. It could be related?

Comment: Yes it is. They must be constant.